# Pyrhon, plotly отображение сетки

Tags: python, plotly

Как сделать сетку пунктирной(grid)?
https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/ Подходящие свойства тут не нашел.
Код:

```
xaxis1={**dict(title_text=x1['title'],#вертикальная сетка
                                     titlefont=dict(color="Black",
                                                   size=font_size_axis_label),
                                    tickfont=dict(color="black",
                                                  size=tickfont_size),
                                    linecolor='black',
                                    gridwidth=1,
                                    gridcolor='gray'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fig.update_xaxes(gridcolor='black', griddash='dash', minor_griddash="dot")
```

Подробно по стилизации линий вы можете ознакомится на примерах на официальном сайте [на примерах на официальном сайте](https://plotly.com/python/axes/)